# The volume control for my Samsung Smart TV app does not work on 12TV_7 group however they work fine on 2013 and 2014 models

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

The volume controls are working fine on 2013 and 2014 models of Samsung smart TV, however the seller store has rejected the app as the volume control does not work on 12TV_7 group. Could anyone please provide some assistance. And also let me know where to test my build for this 12TV_7 as it is not available on RTS.

Comment: SO is not a consumer product support site.

Comment: @ songdogtech I have posted the question on SamsungDForum too. But there has been no reply yet.

Answer (score 1):

How do you handling volume? Do you handling it directly in our app? I think better volume handling is unregistred volume keys from the app and handling volume directly by the TV...